# Python placeholders in strings containing the % symbol

Tags: python, placeholder

I want to be able to use a placeholder in a string that already contains a `%` symbol. For instance, I would like to be able to iterate to open multiple URLs by my URL already contains a `%` symbol, example url:

```
http://www.example.com/BLABLA%123BLABLApage=1
```

To do so, I want to replace the number 1 by a placeholder (`%d`), but the code seems to be confused by the presence of the `%` that comes before the placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape `%` by doubling it:

```
>>> 'http://www.example.com/BLABLA%%123BLABLApage=%d' % (1,)
'http://www.example.com/BLABLA%123BLABLApage=1'
```

Alternatively, use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) formatting instead:

```
>>> 'http://www.example.com/BLABLA%123BLABLApage={:d}'.format(1)
'http://www.example.com/BLABLA%123BLABLApage=1'
```

Comment: Probably want to add use of `format` like `"http://www.example.com/BLABLA%123BLABLApage={page}".format(page=1)`